# extjs how to determine if combobox change event was fire by user

Tags: extjs

I am trying Extjs and I am trying this scenario: I have a combobox which will display the first level in a hierarchy by default. That is to say:

```
0001
0001.0002
0001.0002.0004
0001.0003
0005
```

First level would be `0001` and `0005`. If I select `0001` it goes into the restapi and fetches `0001.0002` and `0001.0003`. That behavior is working as expected. My problem is this: I have to show the fetched data in this very same combobox and to keep selected the item I chose first. What my combo is doing is loading the data, but unselecting everything. Here is what I did so far:

```
var store = Ext.create('mycomponents.store.mystore', {});
var selectedText = '';
var autoSelec = false;

Ext.define('mycomponents.view.myview', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    id: 'myview',
    alias: 'widget.newComponent',
    xtype: 'myview',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            reference: 'levels',
            publishes: 'value',
            fieldLabel: 'Options',
            displayField: 'val',
            valueField: 'val',
            queryMode: 'local',
            lastQuery: '',
            emptyText: 'Please select...',
            anyMatch: true,
            anchor: '-15',
            store: store,
            minChars: 0,
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            selectOnFocus:true,
            typeAheadDelay: 100,
            labelWidth: 100,
            labelAlign: 'right',
            width: 265,
            pageSize: 0,
            clearFilterOnBlur: true,
            defaultValue: 0,
            matchFieldWidth: false,
            allowBlank: false,
            forceSelection: true,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            onTrigger2Click: function (args) {
                this.select(this.getStore().getAt(0));
            },
            listeners: {
                select: function (combo, record, eOpts) {
                    console.log('Select', combo, record, eOpts);
                },

                change: function (item, newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (!autoSelec && newValue !== oldValue && !store.isLoading() && item.selection) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            selectedText = newValue;
                        }

                        store.proxy.extraParams = {
                            sort: 'clave',
                            'filter[activo]': true,
                            'filter[idpadre]': item.selection.data.idelemento
                        };

                        store.load({
                            callback: function () {
                                var items = store.data.items;

                                if (items.length) {
                                    console.log('MY STORE >>>', items);
                                }

                                autoSelec = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var that = this;
    }
});
```

How can I set the previous chosen item as the selectt item after the store load and therefore not to allow the reload of the store?

Comment: Do your work in the select event, instead of the change, `select` won't fire when you set it programatically

Comment: @JuanMendes how can I put the last selected item in the top of the combobox?

Comment: Is your original question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after of spent all day long of searching and reading. Maybe this could sound very naive, but I'm starting with Extjs.

Here is the solution:

```
var items = store.data.items;
store.insert(0, mypreviousElement);
item.setValue(items[0]);
item.focus();
```

from here, item is my combo... this is a callback after `store.load`, hope this might help.